# In easyTable "java", is there a possibility to access the last row i created?

Tags: java, pdfbox

in TableBuilder exactly , can i access the last row ?

There is nothing in the doc of the library explains how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this [easytable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable) library, when you try to build a `Row`, it will return the `Row` Object to you:

```java
public Row build() {
    final Row row = new Row(cells);
    row.settings = settings;
    row.height = height;

    return row;
}
```

So before you call `addRow()` to add your last `Row` to `Table`, you can assign your last `Row` to a variable first.

```java
Row lastRow = Row.builder().build();
Table table = Table.builder().addRow(lastRow);
```

And you can get access to last Row with `lastRow`.